# How to use OnChanged and Validator together?

Tags: forms, validation, flutter, textfield

I have a field to enter pincode. I am presently using a `textFormField` for the same. I have added a validator to it. When the user enters 6 digits, I want to hit server and fetch city and state corresponding to pincode but  to do so, I guess I need `onChanged` property of `textField`.

I would prefer to use  `textFormField` so that the validation is consistent with other fields. Is there any way to do both?
I basically need a way to detect 6 digits have been enetered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on the `onChanged` method call `Form.validate()` :

```
 if(Form.validate()){
   if(textFieldController.text.length == 6){
     // your action here
   }
 }
```

Comment: So I should create a separate form for this field right? I have many fields in my form whose validation should happen later only.

Comment: you have to if you want to achieve what you want

Comment: The code above seems to suggest that you can call `validate()` on the class `Form`. You can not. `validate()` is not a static method.